# Access other .ipa's files installed on my iphone via my app

Tags: ios, swift, security, sandbox

Can I access other .ipa files present on my iphone via my app and pass it to the backend server.

Will I be able to do that after jailbreak? If not on a non-jailbroken device.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO.

Other than that you can register the app as an app that works with different file types and the user can open them manually. Take a look of different App Extensions types Document Provider and Share.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get exact IPA file.

You can get it's container from XCode if it is your app, In container you will found document directory of app where you might have saved data to get this 
  
 Goto **xcode** -> **Device And Simulator**  -> **Select your Device** -> **choose Application**

Press **Setting button** on bottom and press **download container**

[image]

Comment: I am asking about while my app is running on the device can I get access to other .ipa files present on the device.

Comment: @Kapil You can't

Comment: will I be able to do that after jailbreak?

Comment: @Kapil Not sure about this